# Old sci-fi movie about scientist who built a telescope and saw the face or eyeball of God

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading (back in the 80's) in a book about a sci-fi movie that was probably made sometime between 1940's - 1960's (apologies if this is too broad a range).

The book had a photo of a man looking into a large (round) display screen. The screen was part of a telescope that the man had built for investigating the universe. Supposedly he eventually saw the face or the eyeball of God in the display screen.

Would anyone know the name of this movie?

Answer (score 7):

Could this be [*X: The Man with the X-ray Eyes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_The_Man_with_the_X-ray_Eyes) (1963)? It wasn't a telescope, but he did see the "eye that sees us all".

> [A strange one](http://obsidianrook.com/doomfiles/X-RAY_EYES.html), even by Roger Corman standards, I would say...  a scientific experiment gone astray leaves a man with "X-Ray Eyes" -- clearly the inspiration here is those magazine ads for "x-ray specs", but instead of teen titilation, what you get is a rather slow, grim, story about a haggard man who has these stranges attacks where he sees through everything, **he sees too far and what he sees is a giant eye staring back at him.  The eye of god? His own gaze looping around the curve of the universe?**

Comment: And if so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283040/an-old-movie-where-a-doctor-invents-a-drug-in-the-form-of-eyedrops-giving-him-th