# An old movie where a doctor invents a drug in the form of eyedrops giving him the ability to see through objects

Tags: story-identification, movie

When I was a child some decades ago I saw on TV an old movie where a surgeon invented a drug in the form of eyedrops, giving him the ability to see through objects.

In the beginning, he uses it to perform operations without using X-ray devices, but after a short while, he gets banned and hunted and needs to run away throughout America while he can't stop using his eye drug.

I think it was called "Mr. X" and it was filmed during the 1980's. Can you provide its name and more details?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is *[X: The Man with the X-ray Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_The_Man_with_the_X-ray_Eyes)* (1963).

> Dr. James Xavier develops eye drops intended to increase the range of
> human vision, allowing one to see beyond the visible spectrum into the
> ultraviolet and x-ray wavelengths and beyond. Believing that testing
> on animals and volunteers will produce uselessly subjective data, he
> tests the drops on himself.
>
> Initially, Xavier discovers that he can see through people's clothing,
> and he uses his vision to save a young girl whose medical problem was
> misdiagnosed. Over time and with continued use of the drops, Xavier's
> visual capacity increases but his ability to control it decreases.
> Eventually, he can see the world only in forms of light and texture
> that his brain is unable to fully comprehend. Even closing his eyes
> brings no relief, as he can see through his closed eyelids.